# What does "FRANCE TO PLACE" mean?

Tags: meaning, literature

From *Pat Hobby, Putative Father* by F. Scott Fitzgerald:

> He searched the orange pages frantically. Below the form sheets, the
>   past performances, the endless oracles for endless racetracks, his eye
>   was caught by a one-inch item:
>
> LONDON. SEPTEMBER 3RD. ON THIS MORNING'S DECLARATION BY CHAMBERLAIN,
>   DOUGIE CABLES 'ENGLAND TO WIN. **FRANCE TO PLACE**. RUSSIA TO SHOW'.

Clearly this is a shorthand for something, but what?

Comment: Win, place, and show are betting terms, often used in horse racing.

Comment: "ENGLAND TO WIN" is likely a reference to the war, nascent at the time.

Comment: Not Nascent: on 3rd September 1939 Chamberlain declared war on Germany. Who was Dougie in the book? Why is the message on the sporting page? What is the context?

Comment: @WeatherVane The Cambridge Dictionary defines "nascent" as "only recently formed or started, but likely to grow larger quickly." So of course WW2 was nascent in September 1939.

Comment: Anyway, it's just a short story, not a book, and Dougie is not a character (this is the first and only reference to that name). I guess I am closer to understanding what this is supposed to mean -- thanks y'all.

Comment: WW2 was nascent in the mid-30's and everybody knew it was inevitable. When war was declared, that was more explosion than nascence, which isn't really the right usage for an outbreak of war.

Comment: Dougie is likely to refer to Édouard Daladier, the French prime minister at the time. The comma is headlinese for "and": "declaration by Chamberlain and Dougie."

Comment: For another popular culture reference, the use of "place" in this way was vital to the con in *The Sting*.

Comment: https://www.calracing.com/racing-info/racing-101/how-to-bet/
Your bet wins money according to this:
win: 1st place
place: 1st or 2nd place
show: 1st, 2nd or 3rd place

Answer (score 51):

It's a betting term.
Win — first place.
Place — second or first place.
Show — third, second or first place.

Source: [oddsshark.com](https://www.oddsshark.com/horse-racing/win-place-and-show-wagering) (among others).

Suggesting England would "win," France would finish second and Russia third. That is, someone was setting odds on the outcome of the war.

Comment: How does that make sense in this context? Are there second and third place winners in war?

Comment: @Guest it was a **cable** (or **telegram**) which was expensive to send, thus in shorthand, from someone with a sense of humour.

Comment: @Guest “England set to win; France set to come second; Russia set to come third [=last?]”. Makes perfect sense in the context, doesn’t it?

Comment: It is possible that this makes sense, but not to me (yet), and your comment does not help me understand. I understand that this is a metaphor, but as I said, I have not heard of second and third place winners in war. What does that mean?

Comment: @Guest perhaps it was a drole comment about their expected performance.

Comment: @Guest On Sept. 3, 1939, British Prime Minister Neville Chamberlain declared war against Germany. In this context, it appears someone was predicting order of finish of the parties at war, using a horse race as metaphor for war. It has been said nobody wins at war, but this suggests England would gain the most (hence, win), or come out the most "ahead."

Comment: @Guest - You are exactly right, and that's much of the point.  Think about it.

Comment: @guest horseraces often have 10 or more participants in a single race.  As such, even showing (third place) is considered an achievement.  Being picked to show should not be considered disparaging.

Comment: Last line from the epic film _The Unknown Soldier:_ "The Soviet Union won the war but the little and tough Finland became second."

Comment: @Guest The great costs of waging a war, coupled with what is typically a negotiated peace afterwards, will inevitably lead to different nations winning more, losing less, etc. Since we are talking WWII, yes, the Allies won and the Axis lost, but those are sides. Now start counting what each nation had to spend during the war, the losses they took, etc. and you end up with a view that could be close to what was predicted: England was never invaded, France was totally (but very rapidly) occupied and Russia lost about 10 million people.

Comment: @Guest I think it helps to imagine “Dougie” as a horse racing fanatic who would bet on anything.

Comment: It seems that the  betting terms are not related to winning the war, but to declare war on Germany. England to declare first, and so on.

Comment: "second or first place" instead of "first or second place" and "third, second or first place" instead of "first, second or third place' is making me twitch.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you wouldn't say that the loser(s) of a war "placed" or "showed", even in a war with only two or three combatants.  Second and third place in a horse race are still good results and not considered "losing".  (I think you could say that the loser of a two-sided war "placed" if you meant to indicate that the victory was [Pyrrhic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory), though.)

Answer (score 6):

horse racing term

**to place** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/place)

> Games Second position for betting purposes, as in a horserace.

The prediction of the race is for England to win ... Russia to come in 3rd.  But without more context ( doubtful horses name's could be England, France and Russia) it could be a political or some such **metaphor**.

Comment: The relevant context is "September 3rd". Britain declared war on Germany on September 3rd.

Answer (score 3):

> Below the form sheets, the past performances, the endless oracles for endless racetracks

The context is a newspaper for horse racing bettors.

> LONDON. SEPTEMBER 3RD. ON THIS MORNING'S DECLARATION BY CHAMBERLAIN

On September 1st, Germany invaded Poland. As a result, on September 3rd 1939 British Prime Minister Chamberlain declared war on Germany.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtJ_zbz1NyY

> DOUGIE CABLES 'ENGLAND TO WIN. FRANCE TO PLACE. RUSSIA TO SHOW'.

As others have noted, this is horse race betting parlance for England will win, France will come in second, Russia will come in third.